# What were K&R doing here with this linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I was doing a hackerRank challenge with dictionaries in C and I tore some code out of the K&R book.   I dont understand how they are establishing a bucket of linked lists inside a hashtable with this?? It appears to me they are linking the next pointer to the head of the linked list. Are they creating a bucket in in some way im not catching? np is a three member struct containing a strings(name,defn) and the pointer to the next,lookup finds if np is exists in the dictionary.

```
if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL){ // file not found
    np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
    if (NULL == np || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    hashval = hash(name);
    np->next = hashtab[hashval]; // WHAT THE HECK ARE THEY DOING HERE?!?!
    hashtab[hashval] = np;
}else{ // already there
    free((void *)np->defn);
}
if((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
return np;
```

I modified the code as follows to get it to work, but I have a nagging feeling that a missed a point they were trying to make.

```
if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { // not found
    np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
    if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    hashval = hash(name);
    phE->next = NULL; //if first entry set next to NULL, MOD HERE
    tmpNode = hashtab[hashval]; 
    if (tmpNode == NULL){ // EMPTY SPOT IN HASHTABLE
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }else{                         //HASH COLLISION, ADD NODE TO LIST END
        while (tmpNode->next != NULL){
            tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
        }
        tmpNode->next = np;
    }
}else{
    free((void *) np->defn);
}
if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
return np;
```

Comment: They are inserting to the head of a linked list.

Comment: Inserting to the head of a linked list means that insertion is O(1) instead of O(n) as it would be if you traverse the list to find the end.  Sometimes a list that wants end-insertion will also store an "end" pointer in the control block to avoid this.

Comment: @0xsmash0th: What't `phE`? It is not mentioned anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Let's trace through this code to see what it does:

```
np->next = hashtab[hashval]; // WHAT THE HECK ARE THEY DOING HERE?!?!
hashtab[hashval] = np;
```

Initially, our hash table looks something like this:

```
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |   ...   | hashval |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
                              |
                              |
                              |      +------+    +-----+
                              +----> | head | -> | ... |
                                     +------+    +-----+
```

Here's `np`:

```
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |   ...   | hashval |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
                              |
                              |
                 +-----+      |      +------+    +-----+
           np -> |     |      +----> | head | -> | ... |
                 +-----+             +------+    +-----+
```

Now, we set `np->next = hashtab[hashval]`. Now things look like this:

```
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |   ...   | hashval |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
                              |
                              |
                 +-----+      |      +------+    +-----+
           np -> |     |------+----> | head | -> | ... |
                 +-----+             +------+    +-----+
```

Now, both the newly-created cell's next pointer and `hashtab[hashval]` point to the same thing. From the perspective of `np`, it now points to the list formed by prepending the new cell, then using all existing cells.

Finally, we do `hashtab[hashval] = np`, which looks like this:

```
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |   ...   | hashval |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---   ---+---------+---+---+---+
                              |
                    +---------+
                    |
                    v         
                 +-----+             +------+    +-----+
           np -> |     |-----------> | head | -> | ... |
                 +-----+             +------+    +-----+
```

This splices the new element to the front of the linked list.

In other words, this is a pretty typical list prepend made a bit trickier by the use of arrays of linked list pointers.

Comment: I did indeed miss the point of what they were doing! I never even thought about pre-pending! Great drawing was helpful also!

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the basic idiom for inserting a new node *as the first node* in the list.

If `head` points to the current beginning of the list (null pointer for empty list) and `node` points to the new node, then all you need to do is

```
node->next = head;
head = node;
```

and you are done.

These two lines is exactly what you see in the K&R code you quoted.

Your version of the code insists on inserting the new node *at the end of the list.* In a basic implementation of a hash set the order of elements in a bucket does not really matter, which is why the K&R implementation simply inserts the new nodes at the start of each bucket. It is very simple and efficient, as you can see.

If you want to store each bucket's nodes in the order of their arrival, then you have to add the new nodes at the end of the list, which is notably less efficient in your implementation. But if you insist on it, you can use another idiomatic way of doing it, which allows you to avoid special `if` branch for empty buckets

```
struct nlist **pnext = &hashtab[hashval];
for (; *pnext != NULL; pnext = &(*pnext)->next);

*pnext = np;
np->next = NULL;
```

Of course, a more efficient way of doing all this would be to store two pointers for each bucket: to both the first and the last element of the list.

Comment: Very helpful, I totally had a mental block about needing to add a node only to the end. I'll def use that for loop if I need to post-pend a node in the future!